# How to create a page with a cloud of product tags

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently building a bookshop with WooCommerce and I'm using the product tags as authors. The idea is to create a page with a tag cloud (thus, the authors), I looked over the [WC documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-widgets/) and found this:

> WooCommerce Product Tags  – Display product tags in tag cloud format

Thing is: I have no idea of how to use it, I looked over the `template-tags.php` and found this:

```
<div class="tag_cloud">
  <?php wp_tag_cloud(); ?>
</div>
```

Am I supposed to change this to something else in order to display a cloud of products tags?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
wp_tag_cloud(array('taxonomy' => 'product_tag'));
```